# Using ArcMap tool to create a weighted points in each village

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I have 3 layers:

1. layer of districts; (shapefile)
2. layer of cadaster(village) inside each district; (shapefile)
3. Geodatabase that containes info about each cadaster with latitude and longitute, number of houses, number of people inside each house and more info.

What I need to do is, for each cadastre I need to create a point that make the sum of all houses inside this cadastre, and I need to display on top of each point, the number of houses and the number of habitants.

I tried the aggregate tool, statistics tool, and the spatial analysis tools, but it didn't get me the right result that I really want.

Comment: 3. To me it sounds like number three is what you want? is this a point feature class with a point for each cadastre and attributes for the number of houses and people?

Comment: in each cadasters we have hundreds of points with lat/long and other data

Comment: so I need to make a sum with count, and create a point in each cadaster which the size varies from cadaster to another according to it's count of points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Buffer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) your points using a buffer distance that makes your groups touch eachother. This will make circles. (or buffer the cadastres if thats a central point that the houses are around)
2. [dissolve](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) the buffered output, unticking the box asking if you want to create multipart features. This will create a polygon for each cluster of points.
3. Perform a one to many [spatial join](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) between the polygons and the original points. This will create a copy of the polygon for each point, with the original attributes
4. Dissolve using Target_fid as the dissolve field, and add statistics fields using SUM to add up the number of houses, people etc. The will create a polygon for each cadastre with the numbers added up
5. If you have ET Gepowizards run polygon to points selecting the 'centers' options. If not add fields for XY, calculate geometry to get the centroid x and y, export to a table and display xy events.